# Why redux create state in store with '0' name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use React, Redux and Redux-saga. For reducers I use `combineReducers()`. In the reducer I set initial state like this:

```
const authentication = (state = [{isAuthenticated: false}], action) => 
  {  
     switch (action.type) {
       case USER_LOGIN_TRY:
         return Object.assign({}, state, userLogin(action.email))
     default:
       return state;
     }
  }
```

This creates the `authentication` object with the variable `isAuthenticated`. However, when I retrieve this value from state, after the initial state is set, I see in Redux DevTools (and in the console) that redux created the field with name '0' and my initial state.

[image: Why redux create this field? Can i disable this?]

Why does Redux creates this field? Can I disable this? I don't want to create several code blocks for inspecting field with '0' prefix in my code.

Comment: `state = [{isAuthenticated: false}]`: state is an array in which you've added an object. `0` is the index of the object's position in the array. Just have state as the object if you don't want the array.

Comment: Ooo. I add second [ ] brackets, because thinking that it needed for combineReducers() and forgot, that it create 0 index in array. Thank you so much! Please, answer that question and i mark it solution. You save my night:)

Answer (score 2):

doing `state = [{isAuthenticated: false}]` makes your `default` an array